# Ферязь в значении «ферзь»

Tags: лексика, значение-слов

У А. Грина в повести "Бегущая по волнам" в главе X описывается сцена игры в шахматы.

> — Партию в шахматы? — сказал он учтиво. — Если вам угодно.
>
> Я согласился. Мы поставили шахматный столик и сели. Фигуры были
> отличной слоновой кости, хорошей, художественной работы. Я выразил
> удивление, что вижу на грузовом судне много красивых вещей.
> <...>
> Он молчал, трудясь над задачей, которую я поставил ему **ферязью** и
> конем. Внезапно он смешал фигуры и объявил, что проиграл партию. Так
> повторилось два раза; наконец, я обманул его ложной надеждой и объявил
> мат в семь ходов.

Гугл указывает, что ферязь — это устаревший вид одежды. В какой момент времени использовалось слово **ферязь** для описания шахматной фигуры?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Слово [*ферязь*](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_fwords/11847/%D0%A4%D0%95%D0%A0%D0%AF%D0%97%D0%AC) (*ферезь*) имеется в словарях:
ф., ферзь — в шахматной игре — королева (Ф. Павленков, 1907);
так же назыв. одна из фигур в шахматах, иначе — королева, дама, ферязь (М. Попов, 1907);
королева в шахматной игре, иначе ферзь (А. Н. Чудинов, 1910).

Про XVIII век ничего сказать не могу, а вот в девятнадцатом и первой трети двадцатого ("Бегущая по волнам" — 1926 год) слово употреблялось в этом значении.

Между тем как князь Петр живмя жил в кают-компании, между тем как иной шалун, лукаво улыбаясь, замечал, что самая слабая его игра ― шах **ферязи**, капитану Правину припала необыкновенная охота к письменным делам... (А. А. Бестужев-Марлинский. Фрегат «Надежда» (1833)).

Нынешние молодые люди считают нелепым фарсом даже удачу этого рода; они хотят вести правильную, серьезную игру и потому считают вовсе не нужным с первого же разу выводить слона и **ферязь**, чтобы на третьем ходе дать шах и мат королю (Н. А. Добролюбов. Литературные мелочи прошлого года (1859)).